# Why sftp doesn't allow grep command?

Tags: grep, sftp

```
sftp> grep "hello" login.php
Invalid command.
```

I am in the directory which contain login.php.

Comment: Why would it? If you want to run commands, use SSH.

Comment: `grep` is not in the list of "INTERACTIVE COMMANDS" (cf `man sftp`)

Answer (score 4):

`sftp` is just a file transfer tool: it supports a specific set of commands listed on [its man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp). Please run `man sftp` on your own system to see an accurate list of sftp commands for your specific version of sftp.

In order to be able to run `grep` on a remote file, one of two things should happen:

- The file transfer tool might present the remote files as a local filesystem, transferring the contents of each accessed file to your computer whenever required. Then you could use your system's normal `grep` utility to search the contents. The `sshfs` tool can do this. Obviously, the responsiveness of a `sshfs` filesystem will be slower than a real local filesystem.
- Or the file transfer tool might run the `grep` command on the remote system and return only the results back to you. But then the file transfer tool would have to support the remote `grep` operation specifically, and the remote server would have to also either have the support for that specific operation, or allow running arbitrary commands as the logged-in user. But the latter is exactly what the `ssh` command already does, so it does not make sense for the `sftp` command to duplicate that functionality.

Furthermore, the set of operations supported by `sftp` is chosen specifically to limit the operations to file transfer-related things only. The value of this is that the remote system administrator might choose to allow you `sftp` access while not allowing you to log in and run arbitrary commands.

If a user has only a well-known, limited set of operations available, it will be possible for the system administrator (or a system architect designing a secure environment) to effectively reason about what the user could or could not do if they turn out to be malicious. With the full open-ended set of command-line tools available to the user, that task would be much harder.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount sftp folder to a host where you have all rights to execute any command. There you can operate that folder as you wish.